# Summarize Pandas dataframe when column is between two values

Tags: python, pandas

In python, I have a `Pandas` dataframe (df) that can be replicated with the below.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['2021-09-12', 'item1', 'IL', 5], ['2021-09-12', 'item2', 'CA', 7], ['2021-08-13', 'item2', 'CA', 8], ['2021-06-12', 'item3', 'NY', 10], ['2021-05-01', 'item1', 'IL', 11]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'product', 'state', 'sales'])
```

I also have two strings.

```
startdate = '2021-08-01'
enddate = '2021-09-12'
```

I am trying to group by product and state, and add a column `df['sum_sales']` that sums up `df['sales']` when `df['date']` is between startdate and enddate.

I tried to do a `df.groupby(['product', state'])` but not sure how to add the condition above.

Comment: First filter using your dates, then do groupby, not the other way round.

Comment: I eventually need to add multiple columns with different date combinations to a single table, similar to SUM CASE WHEN in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) and [`groupby.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html).

1. `between` will return a Boolean if the condition is satisfied - your conditions are the dates here.
2. `loc` will filter down the DataFrame using the Boolean returned
3. `groupby.sum()` will give return the sum of sales.

```
startdate = '2021-08-01'
enddate = '2021-09-12'

>>> df.loc[df.date.between(startdate,enddate)].groupby(['product', 'state'])['sales'].sum()

product  state
item1    IL        5
item2    CA       15
```

Note that your date is of type `object` from the way you define your inputs.